# HTML breaking in iframe src

Tags: html, iframe, coldfusion

We have a ColdFusion application with a lot of legacy code and a lot of newer code. When rendering the legacy code that hasn't been updated yet, we display it in an iframe. However, a security scan of our software reported issues with some pages breaking when you include html in the url.

Example breaking url: `https://mySite.com/coldfusionPage.cfm?layout=true&67c26"><a>bb6cb=1`

When the iframe renders this, it breaks because the quotes and brackets in the url end the iframe tag, and the rest of the url and iframe tag just gets rendered as html on the page.

Comment: are you rendering the iFrame from a request parameter passed into the ColdFusion application or doing this on the client side?

Comment: Perhaps you should start by looking to see how that url gets generated.

Comment: The parameters on the url were auto-appended by the security app testing for XSS. The iFrame is rendered inside of a .cfm layout file that includes the original url that was hit into the src of the iFrame.

Comment: As Dan said, show us the `<iframe>` code. That's where you're problem is, it sounds like that's retrieved from a url param itself. The security program is specially encoding & the browser's url so that it's passed to the page as part of the url variable, and that's where the break is occuring.

Comment: Did you try url encoding your request?

Answer (score 1):

If you are including that param without scrubbing it for malicious content then your scan company is right. You are open to someone passing a link that puts content on your page (never a good thing). You don't want to pass things through the URL that are then inserted into the url of an iFrame. Think about it. If you had the following a link like this:

```
href="https://mySite.com/myPage.cfm?Include=someIframPage.cfm
```

and then you inserted "someIframePage.cfm" into the target url of your iframe, someone could come along and simply embed some other page there - and send out emails to phish your site.

You need to make sure that ANY url that is passed in is named properly includes only things you know should be there and is scrubbed of HTML before you use it anywhere.

---

EDIT NOTE:

I noticed you responded saying you are not passing the iframe page as a param - yet you *are* putting unprotected HTML on the page through your missing template handler or whatever.  In your example of the scan companie's code they passed `true&67c26"><a>bb6cb=1`, as benign HTML then dinged you for allowing unprotected HTML on the page - as they should. What if I chose:

```
https://mySite.com/coldfusionPage.cfm?layout=true&67c26"><iframe src="http://www.mysiteurl.com/somemaliciouscode.php">bb6cb=1
```

... as my "specially encoded" url param? Could I then embed an iframe on your page? Anything that allows users to inject html onto the page is de facto a security risk. User input (url params, form params, cookies) must be scrubbed and vetted before it is used. That's simple best practice for security of your page. Sorry - but I think your scan company got it right and I have looked at a *ton* of scan reports :)

Comment: My understanding that the scan company is not necessarily right, but they are generating query strings that include characters they shouldn't.

Comment: No I think their job is to test for this exact sort of thing :)

Comment: The iFrame page is not getting passed as a parameter. When they hit the page `https://mysite.com/mypage.cfm?param1=true`, it uses an OnMissingTemplate function to check the database and finds the layout for mypage.cfm. It'll load the appropriate layout.cfm page which includes an iframe that mypage.cfm?param1=true loads inside of.

Answer (score 0):

We answered this ourselves by adding an IIS rule for Request Filter that blocked the specific characters that could break the iframe that the page was getting included in. We had several checks in place and those checks would often take care of the problem but this one specific page was bypassing those checks somehow. The IIS rule fixed that.